# Android - Setup Novell GroupWise Calendar sync

Tags: android, calendar, synchronization, groupwise

Essentially, I just found out that my School is using the useless Novel GroupWise client for correspondence and I only use Hotmail and Google. My email and calendar are both in Google but I (now) have a separate email and calendar for school too. They add appointments and class dates to it. Really annoying. I use my Android for everything, And I want a way to sync my Calendar from GroupWise (well even if it simply receives the appointments I'll be happy).

I log into the groupwise using mail.law.ac.uk/gw/webacc

I tried to setup a Server in Google Calendar on my Android using that URL, but that did not work... Does anyone know how to get the server address, or a way to link my Google to GroupWise?

As for the Mail, I have managed to setup email forwarding in GroupWise, so that's 1 problem sorted. Just calendar issue remains.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GroupWise supports ActiveSync to mobile devices.  Contact you schools IT department again asking where is the GroupWise Mobility Server (Novell Data Synchronizer Mobility Pack for GroupWise).  ActiveSync is a bi-directional sync of Calendar, Contacts and Email protocol from Microsoft which is what the GroupWise Mobility Service does 100%.

This GroupWise Mobility Server is documented at https://www.novell.com/products/groupwise/features/mobile-email-sync.html?ref=h

Here is a video covering the GroupWise mobile solutions topic - 
https://www.novell.com/media/content/mobility-solutions-for-novell-groupwise.html

GroupWise 2012 is the latest version of GroupWise.  This Mobility Solution works for GroupWise v8 and v2012.

Comment: Very good info. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

After contacting my schools IT department. They stated that GroupWise (at least the client we use in school) does not support Calendar access through an App using perhaps LDAP or equivalent.

So there is no solution in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (somewhat free) product to synchronize your Groupwise calendar to Google and vice versa.

http://www.syncjob.com

It is free (but will only sync 5 days ahead)